# Why won't this mergeSort work?

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, mergesort

Okay the purpose of this bit of my program is to take in an unsorted array list of objects and sort it according to the getRaised() method in each object, which returns an integer, using the recursive mergeSort method. The program is running without error, but it is not sorting the arraylist.

```
public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<Runner> runners, int min, int max){
    if(min < max){
        int mid = (min+max)/2;
        mergeSort(runners, min, mid);
        mergeSort(runners, mid+1, max);
        merge(runners, min, mid, max);
    }
}
public static void merge(ArrayList<Runner> runners, int first, int mid, int last){
    ArrayList<Runner> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    temp = runners;
    int f1 = first;
    int l1 = mid;
    int f2 = mid+1;
    int l2 = last;
    int index = f1;

    for(int i = 0; i < runners.size(); i++){
        temp.add(runners.get(i));
    }

    while(f1 <= l1 && f2 <= l2){
        if(runners.get(f1).getRaised() < runners.get(f2).getRaised()){
            temp.set(index, runners.get(f1));
            f1++;
        }else{
            temp.set(index, runners.get(f2));
            f2++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    while(f1 <= l1){
        temp.set(index, runners.get(f1));
        f1++;
        index++;
    }
    while(f2<=l2){
        temp.set(index, runners.get(f1));
        f2++;
        index++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<=runners.size();i++){
        runners.set(i,temp.get(index));
    }

}
```

This is the entire Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Donation {
  protected static ArrayList<Runner> Runners = new ArrayList<Runner>();
  public Donation(ArrayList<Runner> runners){
    for(int i = 0; i < runners.size(); i++){
        Runners.add(runners.get(i));
    }       
    mergeSort(Runners, 0,Runners.size()-1);
}

public void addRunner(String n, String id, double r){
    Runners.add(new Runner(n, id, r));
}
public String displayInfo(int index){
    String str = Runners.get(index).toString();
    return str;
}
public void addDonations(int index, double amt){
    Runners.get(index).Raised+=amt;
}
public double getSum(){
    double sum=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Runners.size(); i++){
        sum+=Runners.get(i).Raised;
    }
    return sum;
}
public ArrayList<Runner> getRunnerObj(){
    return Runners;
}
public String goldenSneaker(){
    String gold = "";

    return gold;
}
public String silverSneaker(){
    String silver = "";

    return silver;
}
public String bronzeSneaker(){
    String bronze = "";

    return bronze;
}
public String achillesHeel(){
    String ach = "";

    return ach;
}

public void writeToFile(){

}

public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<Runner> runners, int min, int max){
    if(min < max){
        int mid = (min+max)/2;
        mergeSort(runners, min, mid);
        mergeSort(runners, mid+1, max);
        merge2(runners, min, mid, max);
    }
}

public static void merge2(ArrayList<Runner> runners, int first, int mid, int last){
    ArrayList<Runner> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    int f1 = first;
    int l1 = mid;
    int f2 = mid+1;
    int l2 = last;
    int index = 0;

    for(int i = first; i <=last; i++){
        temp.add(runners.get(i));
    }

    while(f1 <= l1 && f2 <= l2){
        if(runners.get(f1).getRaised() < runners.get(f2).getRaised()){
            temp.set(index, runners.get(f1));
            f1++;
        }else{
            temp.set(index, runners.get(f2));
            f2++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    while(f1 <= l1){
        temp.set(index, runners.get(f1));
        f1++;
        index++;
    }
    while(f2<=l2){
        temp.set(index, runners.get(f2));
        f2++;
        index++;
    }

    index = 0;
    for(int i = first; i<=last;i++){
        runners.set(i,temp.get(index));
        index++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what do you get instead? The original unsorted list?

Comment: Do you really need this temp = runners; in merge method  ?

Comment: Yes. The information is read in from a text file, where the information is sorted by a different attribute. So in all intents and purposes, the information is unsorted. I want to sort it by the amount raised attribute, which is accessed by the getRaised() method.

Comment: Uma: I meant to delete that, it was a failed attempt at a fix

Comment: For the record, your two lines `ArrayList<...> temp = ...;` and `temp = runners;` can be shortened into `ArrayList<...> temp = runners`.

Answer (score 0):

Your merge method has multiple errors :

```
public static void merge(ArrayList<Runner> runners, int first, int mid, int last){
    ArrayList<Runner> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    temp = runners; // remove that line, otherwise your original list will
                    // continue growing until you run out of memory
    int f1 = first;
    int l1 = mid;
    int f2 = mid+1;
    int l2 = last;
    int index = f1;

    for(int i = 0; i < runners.size(); i++){
        temp.add(runners.get(i));
    }

    while(f1 <= l1 && f2 <= l2){
        if(runners.get(f1).getRaised() < runners.get(f2).getRaised()){
            temp.set(index, runners.get(f1));
            f1++;
        }else{
            temp.set(index, runners.get(f2));
            f2++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    while(f1 <= l1){
        temp.set(index, runners.get(f1));
        f1++;
        index++;
    }
    while(f2<=l2){
        temp.set(index, runners.get(f1)); // typo - should be get(f2)
        f2++;
        index++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<=runners.size();i++){ // should be i<runners.size()
                                           // to avoid index out of bounds
                                           // exception
        runners.set(i,temp.get(index)); // should be i instead of index
    }

}
```

This will work, though it's not very efficient, since in each call to `merge` you copy the entire source list to the temp list and back to the source list, while the only indices that should be copied are the indices from first to last.

Here's a more efficient merge :

```
public static void merge(ArrayList<Runner> runners, int first, int mid, int last){
    ArrayList<Runner> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    int f1 = first;
    int l1 = mid;
    int f2 = mid+1;
    int l2 = last;

    while(f1 <= l1 && f2 <= l2){
        if(runners.get(f1).getRaised() < runners.get(f2).getRaised()){
            temp.add(runners.get(f1));
            f1++;
        }else{
            temp.add(runners.get(f2));
            f2++;
        }
    }
    while(f1 <= l1){
        temp.add(runners.get(f1));
        f1++;
    }
    while(f2<=l2){
        temp.add(runners.get(f2));
        f2++;
    }

    // copy only the merged range back to runners
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = first; i<=last;i++){
        runners.set(i,temp.get(index));
        index++;
    }

}
```

I tested it by changing the `ArrayList<Runner>` to `ArrayList<Integer>` and it works.

Comment: Eran: That didn't do it either.

Comment: @MitchellGrayEdwards Yes, it was only one of the errors. See edit.

Comment: that still didn't do it... :/

Comment: The class that this sort is in has a global arrayList called Runners that is one of the attributes. The sort is being called in the class constructor, which passes in this arrayList as an argument. I don't know if this clarifies. But I feel like the mergeSort is sorting, but isn't sorting the class attribute. Like it's sorting, but then nothing happens.

Comment: @MitchellGrayEdwards Well, it works for me when I run it on an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: @MitchellGrayEdwards Try to print the ArrayList before and after the call to mergeSort. Also, you never wrote how you call this method. You should call it with `mergeSort(list, 0, list.size()-1);`

Comment: is the 'ArrayList<Integer>' a class attribute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76297/discussion-between-mitchell-gray-edwards-and-eran).

Comment: @MitchellGrayEdwards edited the answer to be more efficient. You don't need to copy anything from the source list to the temp list at the start of the merge method. Please show the code that calls the mergeSort if you want me to see if there are other errors there.

Comment: I moved it over to chat and added the rest of the class in. The methods in concern are the constructor, the mergeSort(), and merge2, which is your more efficient version.

Comment: How is getRaised() implemented?  If you have a mistake there then being a stable sort the final order will be the original order.  Also a bit more feedback than "It doesn't work" would be much appreciated.  How doesn't it work?  Partly sorted?  Not at all?  Backward?  What?

Comment: @Jason it is a simple 

public double getRaised(){
     return Raised;
}

and it simply reverses the order of the Objects in the ArrayList. It doesn't reorder them according to the getRaised() return.

Comment: That looks like an accidental global variable, which of course won't sort.  Can we see the full object?